# EmojiCode - Trying to figure out how to download packages

Tags: emoji

I know you can import packages using

allegro

but I'm trying to understand this - how to download, what means what, how to import effectively.

```
 Fatal Error: Could not load package "allegro" dlopen(/usr/local/EmojicodePackages/allegro-v0/allegro.so, 1): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/allegro/lib/liballegro.5.2.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/EmojicodePackages/allegro-v0/allegro.so
Reason: image not found.
fish: 'emojicode app.emojib' terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo, I figured it out and it wasn't another guy figuring it out I did it all myself:

```
brew install allegro
```

Right in that command boi.

You GOTTA have that homebrew huh.